# print screen of flash movie and save as image

Tags: flash

I am developing a small flash application.
In my application users should be able to drag different elements from a toolbox into a canvas.
At some point a user will be able to save the different elements he dragged as a picture.
I wanted to know if there is a functionality that prints the screen in flash.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw a Bitmap of the stage by using the BitmapData draw() method , then you could use the PrintJob class to output the resulting Bitmap to the user's printer.

Comment: ok, that's great thank you! Though a quick follow up... assume the user is painting something, and I want to record his painting process so I can play it back to him as a movie, is this possible?